# Calling a function in JavaScript, with a variable in it

Tags: javascript

doing something like:

```
speak('Hello. Today is " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + ", " + hours + ":" + minutes + ". I have couple suggestions of what to do today...Wanna go to the movies? Play some games? Go out to eat? Need anything else?')
```

When it writes them, it literally says `" + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + ", " + hours + ":" + minutes + "`

`speak('')` is a function defined by another script. Is it possible to put variables in it?

Comment: Change the double quotes (`"`) to single quotes (`'`).

Comment: Or change the single quotes to double quotes. That's much faster.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of alternating between single and double quotes.  You want to choose one and use it consistently.  Both styles are allowed (all singles or all doubles) and neither are preferred, so it is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript allows both `'single quotes'` and `"double quotes"` to denote the start and end of Strings.  However, you can't mix and match them.  That is, `'this will cause an error"`.

So, you need to change the program text to:

```
speak('Hello. Today is ' + month + '/' + day + '/' + year + ', ' + hours + ':' + minutes + '. I have couple suggestions of what to do today...Wanna go to the movies? Play some games? Go out to eat? Need anything else?')
```

or to:

```
speak("Hello. Today is " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + ", " + hours + ":" + minutes + ". I have couple suggestions of what to do today...Wanna go to the movies? Play some games? Go out to eat? Need anything else?")
```